# Woocommerce 3 Mini Cart - Filter HTML Output

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm calling a function which is supposed to create custom markup of the woocommerce mini cart:

```
            <?php 

              function tmc_wc_print_mini_cart() {

            ?>
            <div class="widget_shopping_cart">
              <div class="hide_cart_widget_if_empty">
                <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">

                  <?php if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) : ?>
                    <ul class="cart_list product_list_widget ">
                      <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) :
                      $_product = $cart_item['data'];
                      // Only display if allowed
                      if ( ! apply_filters('woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) || ! $_product->exists() || $cart_item['quantity'] == 0 ) continue;
                      // Get price
                      $product_price = get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_display_cart' ) == 'excl' ? $_product->get_price_excluding_tax() : $_product->get_price_including_tax();
                      $product_price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price_html', woocommerce_price( $product_price ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                      ?>
                      <li class="mini_cart_item">
                        <a class="item-link" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $cart_item['product_id'] ); ?>">
                          <div class="item-image">
                            <?php echo $_product->get_image(); ?>
                          </div>

                          <div class="item-details">
                            <span class="name"><?php echo apply_filters('woocommerce_widget_cart_product_title', $_product->get_title(), $_product ); ?></span>
                            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . __('Quantity', 'sage') . ':' . $cart_item['quantity'] . '<span>x</span></span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>

                            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_price', '<span class="price">' . __('Unit Price', 'sage') . ':' . $product_price . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                          </div>

                        </a>
                      </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                  </ul>

                <?php else : ?>

                  <div class="widget_shopping_cart" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="hide_cart_widget_if_empty">
                      <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
                        <ul class="cart_list product_list_widget ">
                          <div class="empty-minicart"><?php _e( 'There are currently no products in your bag.', 'sage' ); ?></div>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart()) > 0) : ?>

                  <p class="total">
                    <strong><?php _e( 'Total', 'sage' ); ?>:</strong>  <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?>  
                  </p>
                  <p class="buttons">
                    <a href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" class="cart btn btn-default">
                      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <?php _e( 'View Bag', 'sage' ); ?>
                    </a>
                  </p>

                <?php endif; ?>

                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
```

When the window is loading the new content within the div "widget_shopping_cart_content" gets removed and the default mini cart markup added? The function is stored in a must use plugin rather than functions.php but I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing here?

Any help would be great

Comment: With woocommerce the mini cart is loaded/refreshed through a function hooked in `woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments`… ajax filter hook, that will target a specific html structure in your theme. May be you should better try to override the template `cart/mini-cart.php` via your active theme instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Hi Loic. Yeah I've tried that already but without success. If I use a template override it's weird because some parts of the override are respected but the parts I really want to change - the markup of the list items - get overwritten and the stardard template markup is used? I'm calling woocommerce_mini_cart within my header.php file.

Comment: So I think I've solved the issue of why template overrides weren't working. Woocommerce was caching the html in session storage so i needed to keep emptying the cart and clearing cache. I am however having a separate issue which I'll ask in a separate question.